# C++ series summation code giving different answers on large input

Tags: c++

I am adding numbers from 1 to n in C++. I have used both the [iteration method](https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-find-sum-first-n-natural-numbers/) and [mathematical formula](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/groups/tatami/kumo/exs/sum/). The code works fine for up to 9 digits.

[image: Same result for both methods]

But when I give input a 10 digit number, the formula and iteration methods give separate answers.

[image: First answer derived from formula and second one from iteration method]

I have tried to look it up on google but couldn't find any solution for this. My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    unsigned long long i, n, sum = 0, out_put;
    cout << "Sum of numbers from 1 to: ";
    cin >> n;

    /// using mathematical formula
    out_put = n*(n+1);
    out_put = out_put/2;
    cout << " =   " << out_put << endl;

    /// using iteration
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        sum = sum+i;
    }
    cout << " ==  " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How do know which one is the correct one? If I assume the formula can't be wrong then why is the iteration method giving incorrect answer? I have used [unsigned long long](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm) to prevent overflow but still didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are seeing is overflow happening on your calculations at different points. `9,999,999,999` * `10,000,000,000` is ~`9.9e19` while an `unsigned long long` holds ~`1.8e19`.  So the result wraps around and you get one answer.

Your for loop is also going to overflow but it is going to do so at a different point meaning the answers will diverge from one another since the modulo arithmetic is happening with a smaller number.

Comment: Thanks, got it. To get around this problem, should I use arrays to store these large numbers?

Comment: @arongka If you want to go this large you are probably going to need a big int library.  A 64 bit integer will only be able to calculate `n(n + 1)` for `n ~= 4.5e9`

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that `n*(n+1)` can be too large to store in an `unsigned long long`, even though the end result (half of that) which you calculate via iteration may still fit.

Assuming your `unsigned long long` has 64 bits, it can hold integers up to 18446744073709551615. Anything above that will restart from 0.

Edit: As Nathan points out, you can of course have both calculations overflow. The sum would still give the correct result modulo `2^64`, but the direct calculation can be off because the division does not generally yield the same result modulo `2^64` after you have wrapped around.

Comment: The end result doesn't fit in a 64 bit `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, Nathan's answer is more correct indeed.

Comment: @MaxLanghof What should be the best way to get around this overflow?

Comment: @arongka Your processor is unlikely to natively support integer arithmetics beyond 64 bit, so you need a software solution - most likely a library for large integers. I don't have any recommendations myself (and they would not be in scope for stackoverflow).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    unsigned long long i, n, sum = 0, out_put;
    cout << "Sum of numbers from 1 to: ";
    cin >> n;

    /// using mathematical formula
    out_put = n*(n+1);
    out_put = out_put/2;
    cout << " =   " << out_put << endl;

    /// using iteration
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        sum = sum+i;
    }
    cout << " ==  " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```